# Recommended way to get hostname in Elixir

Tags: elixir

in nodejs I run

```
 var os = require("os")
 os.hostname()
```

How can I get in elixir?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a function in Elixir's standard library for this but Erlang has [`inet:gethostname/0`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#gethostname-0) which you can call directly:

```
iex(1)> {:ok, hostname} = :inet.gethostname
{:ok, 'dogbert'}
iex(2)> hostname
'dogbert'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for sake of completeness you can also do this:

```
{hostname, exit_status} = System.cmd "hostname", [""]
{"TR01PPL010698\r\n", 0}
```

This works on Windows, *nix and Mac.  As you can see it returns an Elixir binary (as opposed to an Erlang charlist) but you also may need to concern yourself with stripping away line-endings.

Comment: Word of warning: This code returns `{"", 0}` on my Mac running macOS 12 Monterey. Whereas the most up-voted solution `:inet.gethostname/0` works as described.